# Avoiding FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION error using intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bitmap, uri

In my costum camera app I need to transfer a bitmap and a Uri from one activity to another. For some reason I'm getting the FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION error on most phones(I get the error on newer phones but don't on Nexus4 and Galaxy3). I get the same error even when I only try to transfer the Bitmap through an intent(I also tried transfering only the Uri and got the error). From what I've read online the error comes from a memory problem but I don't know how to fix it. I would appreciate any kind of help.

My first Activity:

```
...

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);

            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            ok.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()==btn.getId())
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }
    if(v.getId()==ok.getId())
    {
        String stringUri;
        stringUri = selectedImageUri.toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent .setClass(MainActivity.this,  SecondMain.class);
        intent .putExtra("KEY", stringUri);
        startActivity(intent );
    }

}
```

}

Second Activity:

```
public static Camera isCameraAvailiable(){
    Camera object = null;
    try {
        object = Camera.open();// attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return object; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

private Camera.PictureCallback capturedIt = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        if(bitmap==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        cameraObject.release();


    }

};

 ...

    String stringUri = null;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("KEY")) {
        stringUri= extras.getString("KEY");
    }

    selectedImageUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("KEY"));

    float alpha=(float)1/2;
    img.setAlpha(alpha);
    img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
    cameraObject = isCameraAvailiable();
    showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
    frame.addView(showCamera);
}

public void snapIt(View view){
    redo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ok.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    snap.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    cameraObject.takePicture(null, null, capturedIt);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 if(v.getId()==ok.getId())
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondMain.this, Blend.class);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[]byteArray=stream.toByteArray();
        intent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
        String stringUri;
        stringUri = selectedImageUri.toString();
        intent .putExtra("KEY", stringUri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Add logging to `onClick()` method to see how large your PNG is: `Log.v("DEBUG", "byteArray.length="+byteArray.length);`

Answer (score 5):

It is not a memory problem, it's a problem with transferring your image with your intent. You see, `Bundle` has a limit of how much data it can transfer from one end to the other, currently it's only 1MB. You will problems on all modern phones with a decent camera, as the image exceeds 1MB limit, some old phones with low end camera will work. You need to rethink on how you are going to be transfering the image.

You can

- Save it to a file first, send the only the path to it (that's how selecting an image from the gallery works)
- Save it to SQL and retrive it on the other end
- Make a hodler class with a static variable of image (the most simple)
- Make a custom class of Application and put it there for the time being.
- Downscale and compress the image before it's transferred

Comment: Even when I only transfered the uri (which is the pic from the gallery) I got the error. By the way the intent that has a problem is from the second activity shown to another. I did compress the bitmap in the current version...